# Custom ArchiveFileSystem implementation not working (ArchiveFileSystem, ArchiveFileType and ArchiveHandler implemented)

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for creating mods targeted towards the game DayZ. I have added an implementation of `ArchiveFileSystem`, `ArchiveFileType` and `ArchiveHandler` which have all been added to the projects `plugin.xml`.

With all this being said, when I try to summon an instance of the filesystem with `VirtualFileManager.getInstance().getFileSystem(DAYZ_PBO_PROTOCOL) as PboFilesystem` I end up getting a null pointer.

I assume this means the filesystem isn't getting registered, but this doesn't seem to be the case. ANY help would be great, here's the repository
https://github.com/FlipperPlz/dayzideaplugin/tree/archive/src/main

I have tried switching all implementations to classes as opposed to kotlin objects. I have also tried using `ArchiveFileType` as opposed to the regular FileType implementation with no success.

Comment: The best place to ask would be https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.

Comment: For some reason I can't post on that site without the post getting marked as "pending approval"

Comment: Don't worry, it will get approved by the mods. It looks like the spam filter gets triggered.